# Stripe elements error requires payment method

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement apply pay and google pay using Stripe elements. But stripe keeps giving me the following error
"requires_payment_method".

However, the dashboard is showing a 200 response code (A request to create a PaymentIntent completed) message.

Stripe docs that I'm using
https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

My Code

index.php

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('MY STRIPE KEY');
        
        \Stripe\ApplePayDomain::create([
          'domain_name' => 'www.example.com',
        ]);
        
        $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
          'payment_method_types' => ['card'],   
          'amount' => 2000,
          'currency' => 'usd',
        ])

?>


<div id="payment-request-button">
  <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
</div>  

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="js/payments.js"></script>
```

payments.js

```
    var stripe = Stripe('MY STRIPE PUBLIC KEY', {
      apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
    });

    var paymentRequest = stripe.paymentRequest({
      country: 'US',
      currency: 'usd',
      total: {
        label: 'MY PRODUCT NAME',
        amount: 2000,
      },
      requestPayerName: true,
      requestPayerEmail: true,
    });
    
    var elements = stripe.elements();
        var prButton = elements.create('paymentRequestButton', {
          paymentRequest: paymentRequest,
    });

// Check the availability of the Payment Request API first.
paymentRequest.canMakePayment().then(function(result) {
  if (result) {
    prButton.mount('#payment-request-button');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('payment-request-button').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('no-mob-pay').style.display = 'block';  
  }
});
    
paymentRequest.on('paymentmethod', function(ev) {
  // Confirm the PaymentIntent without handling potential next actions (yet).
  stripe.confirmCardPayment(
    clientSecret,
    {payment_method: ev.paymentMethod.id},
    {handleActions: false}
  ).then(function(confirmResult) {
    if (confirmResult.error) {
      // Report to the browser that the payment failed, prompting it to
      // re-show the payment interface, or show an error message and close
      // the payment interface.
      ev.complete('fail');
    } else {
      // Report to the browser that the confirmation was successful, prompting
      // it to close the browser payment method collection interface.
      ev.complete('success');
      // Check if the PaymentIntent requires any actions and if so let Stripe.js
      // handle the flow. If using an API version older than "2019-02-11"
      // instead check for: `paymentIntent.status === "requires_source_action"`.
      if (confirmResult.paymentIntent.status === "requires_action") {
        // Let Stripe.js handle the rest of the payment flow.
        stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret).then(function(result) {
          if (result.error) {
            // The payment failed -- ask your customer for a new payment method.
            window.location = "www.example.com/order-fail.php";   
          } else {
            // The payment has succeeded.
            window.location = "www.example.com/success.php";  
          }
        });
      } else {
        // The payment has succeeded.
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Hope someone can help me to figure out why I'm seeing this error. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1):

The PaymentIntent status moves to `requires_payment_method` when the payment fails, you should take a look at the [last_payment_error](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-last_payment_error) of the PaymentIntent and understand why it failed.